# How to fade in text elements one by one

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to achieve Marie Forleo's homepage effect **just with css**. But all my elements fades at the same time. How can i fade it one by one?

Here's what i want to accomplish: https://www.marieforleo.com/  (Fade in effect of banner)

Here's my code:

```
test h1 {


    -webkit-animation: fadein 5s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 5s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 5s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 5s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 5s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}



/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: If you want that effect, it can't be done only with CSS. You need Javascript and some scroll up and down events to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `animation-delay` to delay animations. [Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66sj3d51/) where you can see what you need.

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

.fadeInAnimated {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 2s forwards; /* forwards (animation-fill-mode) retains the style from the last keyframe when the animation ends */
}

#second {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

#third {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="first" class="fadeInAnimated">This first</li>
  <li id="second" class="fadeInAnimated">Then this</li>
  <li id="third" class="fadeInAnimated">And lastly this</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code worked like a charm! But the only little thing is.... How can i prevent it to dissapear? @titulum

Comment: @karensantana Updated.

Comment: Thank you @Titulum! You made someone's day. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many items you're going to fade in, you could set a staggered `animation-delay` property on each one.

```
.item_01 {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.item_02 {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're looking for a jQuery solution (you mention css, but you've also tagged jquery) but this will work as well.

You can use 1 selector and call fade in, then in the callback call fadeIn with another selector. By the way, if the pre-sets for fade in ("slow", "fast") don't work for you you can specify numbers in milliseconds.

```
  $( ".item_01" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
     $(".item_02").fadeIn("slow");
  });
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/