# I create Fade in and Fade out effect using Css different ease but

Tags: html, css

I create Fade in and Fade out effect using different CSS ease using this site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function I use few ease codes from that website but It seems like the letters are just blinking, I need them to come in one a time in sequential order (fading in).

```css
.fade-in {
      animation: fadeIn infinite alternate ease 2s;  
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeIn {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="fade-in">Its just fade in not out i want fade in and out in loop never stop it.</h1>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fade in text elements one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349767/how-to-fade-in-text-elements-one-by-one)

Answer (score 1):

To make it feel like fade in and out, assign it a duration, Like:

```
animation: fadeIn 2s infinite alternate ease;
```

- Here the `2s` is the duration or we can say the total time taken by the animation.

```css
.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn 2s infinite alternate ease;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fade-in">Its just fade in not out i want fade in and out in loop never stop it.</h1>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/mdrzmKr

Comment: To make it feel like fade in and out we need to put the same duration as if I put first 2s then I must need to put delay 2s as well or not? if you have any values in your mind to make this text look like fade in and out.

Comment: Even if you will remove the delay, it will work totally fine. I just included it because you had it in your code, just remove the last 2s. And they do not need to be same. without delay, it will look much better.

Comment: @Aziz I have updated the answer, check it.

Comment: @Aziz can you tell me that do you want the fade to be fast or slowly.

Comment: Brother its looks like the letters are just blinking, I want them to come in one a time in sequential order (fading in).

Comment: Do you mean typing effect?

Comment: Slowly show them one at a time starting from the top and then go down.

Comment: Do you want something like this: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/wvzYepE

Comment: Or you want something like this: https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1610478601~acl=%2Fvimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us%2F01%2F4943%2F19%2F499715120%2F2272081581.mp4~hmac=a519743363e612753c3c758c9b99b7573e9ae458622d63647c9b7f2bf74ad96e/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/4943/19/499715120/2272081581.mp4

Comment: I think so we very close, is it poseable fade in start from top and then end down like vertically top to bottom fade-in animation.

Comment: Similar: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/wvzYepE

I’d like it to just appear 

1.

2.

3.

4.

Etc

Comment: Top to bottom: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/xxEyLLp

Comment: it's good, but I need them one at a time the way you have it is all at once?